# Why password validation does not work after adding password recovery?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, authentication, password-encryption, actioncontroller

Faced a problem not clear to me.
I used password validation during registration.

```rb
def pass_val
    if password_digest.count("a-z") <= 0 || password_digest.count("A-Z") <= 0 
      errors.add(:password, "must contain 1 small letter, 1 capital letter and minimum 8 symbols")
    end
  end
validates :password_digest, presence: true,
                            length: { minimum: 8 }
```

I made it possible to recover the password for the user, and validation just stopped working.
I changed all `password_digest` in validation to just `password` and validation worked again.
BUT, after that, password recovery disappeared, which began to curse for validation.

```
NoMethodError in PasswordResetsController#create
undefined method `count' for nil:NilClass
```

If I change all `password` again to `password_digest`, validation will disappear, but the recovery password will work again.

**UPDATE**

1. Using `password` - validation in the console works (it also works on the site. Passwords recovery does not work).
2. Using `password_digest` - validation in the console also works (it doesn’t work on the site, the recovery password works).

**UPDATE 2**
**Moreover, an error occurs during password recovery when a letter is sent to the mail (before sending), and not exactly during the password change.**

**UPDATE 3**
create method in PasswordResetsController:

```rb
def create
  author = Author.find_by_email(params[:email])
  author.send_password_reset if author
  flash[:success] = "Email sent with password reset instructions."
  redirect_to root_path
end
```

**UPDATE 4**
send password_reset:

```rb
  def send_password_reset
    confirmation_token
    self.password_reset_sent_at = Time.zone.now
    save!
    AuthorMailer.password_reset(self).deliver!
  end
```

But the letter is not sent, crashes up to this point.
**I want to emphasize** that I either use `password_digest` in validation and validation does not work, and password recovery works. Or I use `password` in validation and validation works, but password recovery does not.

Also, it’s worth noting that the create method in PasswordResetsController is not used to change the password, but to send an email to the email. I can’t understand why validation swears at him.

Comment: `password_digest` is not the password, so you should not be doing any content check against it.

Comment: what does `send_password_reset` do? show the code. I guess it sends an email with a link, what happens when the user clicks the link? show the code, I guess it shows a form, what happens when the user submits the form? show the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error was in the `send_password_reset` method.
Added `(: validate => false)` to this method and it worked.

```rb
  def send_password_reset
    confirmation_token
    self.password_reset_sent_at = Time.zone.now
    save!(:validate => false)
    AuthorMailer.password_reset(self).deliver!
  end
```

In vallidation i use `password`.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you already found a solution yourself. However I'm not sure you understand **why** this is happening.

Let's start of with the important fact that `password_digest` doesn't contain the password but rather a hashed version of the password. (The result of a hash function is also called a digest.) You'll want to add the validations to the `password` attribute, since that contains the actual password.

When you assign a new password to an author both the password and password digest will be assigned a new value. You could imagine the `password` setter to look something like this:

```
def password=(password)
  @password = password
  @password_digest = do_some_hash_magic(password)
end
```

Because `password` is set when you assign it to the author you're able to validate the contents of it.

Another important thing to know is that the actual password is never saved into the database, only the password digest is (for security reasons). For this reason when you (re)load the instance from the database `password` is set to `nil`, because the application no longer knows what it is.

Instead of skipping the validation with `save(validate: false)`, I suggest using the [`:allow_nil`](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#allow-nil) option or making the [validation conditional](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#conditional-validation) to only trigger the validation when the `password` is not `nil`.

```
validates :password, length: { in: 8..255 }, allow_nil: true

validates :password, format: { with: /\p{Lower}/,    message: :no_lower   }, allow_nil: true
validates :password, format: { with: /\p{Upper}/,    message: :no_upper   }, allow_nil: true
validates :password, format: { with: /\p{Digit}/,    message: :no_digit   }, allow_nil: true
validates :password, format: { with: /[\p{S}\p{P}]/, message: :no_special }, allow_nil: true
```

Alternatively you can be more explicit and use the [`:on`](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#on) option with a custom context to only trigger trigger the validations when you want them to:

```
validates :password, length: { in: 8..255 }, on: :password

validates :password, format: { with: /\p{Lower}/,    message: :no_lower   }, on: :password
validates :password, format: { with: /\p{Upper}/,    message: :no_upper   }, on: :password
validates :password, format: { with: /\p{Digit}/,    message: :no_digit   }, on: :password
validates :password, format: { with: /[\p{S}\p{P}]/, message: :no_special }, on: :password
```

The context doesn't have to be named after an attribute, using `:foo` instead of `:password` would also be just fine. You can then run these validations by passing a context when calling `valid?` or `save`.

```
author.valid?(:password)
author.save(context: :password)
```

If you use Rails 5 or higher you can pass multiple contexts as an array if you want to run a mix of validations. `author.valid?([:create, :password])`

For additional info about the regexes used check out the [Ruby regexp documentation](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.1/doc/regexp_rdoc.html#label-Character+Properties).